# How do I select a certain field from an array of objects of a certain class in Ruby on Rails 2.3.14

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

If I have an array of 100 objects of a class called `Stream`, like this:

```
User.find(1001).streams.find( :all, :order => "id", :limit => 100 )
```

which is basically a data table, how would I select a certain field, such as rating, from it? In SQL, all I need to do is, `SELECT rating FROM streams WHERE user_id=1001 ORDER BY id LIMIT 100`, but I don't know how to do that in Ruby on Rails. Using the command above returns all the fields, which I can't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below will return an array of `rating`

```
User.find(1001).streams.all( :order => "id", :limit => 100).map(&:rating)
```

If you want to avoid the cost of retrieving all attributes of the `User` object:

```
User.find(1001).streams.all:select => "rating", 
  :order => "id", :limit => 100).map(&:rating)
```

You can use the standard `SELECT` clause syntax in the value for the key `:select`.

If you want to avoid constructing `User` objects:

```
User.connection.select_values("select rating from users order by id limit 100")
```